# Python Functions execute in wrong order, why?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the program, it first waits until I enter input, then it will play the sound, then it shows the window with my image. Why is it doing this out of order?

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound

main = Tk()
main.state('zoomed')
main.geometry("1366x768")

# Displays a gif.
def show():
    dollar_canvas = Canvas(width=50, height=50, bg='lightgrey', highlightthickness=0)
    dollar_canvas.place(x=850, y=25)
    my_gif = PhotoImage(file='Dollar50x50.gif')
    dollar_canvas.image = my_gif
    dollar_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=my_gif, anchor=NW)

# Accepts an input, such as enter.
def getinput():
    a = input()

# Plays a ring sound.
def play():
    winsound.PlaySound('money', winsound.SND_ALIAS)


show()
getinput()
play()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Without a running `mainloop()` Tkinter doesn't really work (like showing windows, etc.)

Comment: Not sure I understand. I have the mainloop() at the bottom. If I comment away the getinput() line, it still runs, but plays the sound before showing the dollar sign gif. I want these to execute in order. Why does it play the sound first?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I just started learning python and tkinter. I'll elaborate a little: I do deliveries on the side and wrote a program to track my totals. It accepts six entries, calculates totals, writes them to a file, displays them in a listbox. It works perfectly... but then... I decided it would be cool to play a 'cha-ching' sound and display a dollar sign graphic on the window after I enter a new delivery record. It plays the sound first, then shows the gif. I want the gif to appear first, then the sound. It is doing them out of order. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't running out of order. Throw in a few print statements to see the order they are executing in.  The problem is that until the event loop (`mainloop`) runs, tkinter doesn't have an opportunity to update the display. In your code `mainloop` won't run until the other functions finish.

To force the display to update you can call `root.update_idletasks()`.

Comment: "root.update_idletasks()" Worked! Thanks so much Bryan. Man I have a lot to learn.